# Is there an idiom or a phrase that means "diarrhea prone intestine"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

There's an expression for heartburn if I am not mistaken and it's "upset stomach" as in "I have an upset stomach, so I can't drink beer". However, I can't think of a single idiom or phrase for people who are diarrhea prone and who need to go to the bathroom often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is called [Irritable Bowel Syndrome](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/irritable-bowel-syndrome/symptoms-causes/syc-20360016)

> Irritable bowel syndrome (IBS) is a common disorder that affects the large intestine. Signs and symptoms include cramping, abdominal pain, bloating, gas, and diarrhea or constipation, or both. IBS is a chronic condition that you'll need to manage long term

Comment: In a spoken language, people will likely use the acronym "IBS." The other 2 terms are irritable bowel and sensitive bowel. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4816888/